# What's the datatype of the value returned by octokit.createPullRequest() in octokit-plugin-create-pull-request?

Tags: github, github-api, octokit, octokit-js

I want to make a pull request from a react-native app. I am using the octokit-plugin-create-pull-request library from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/octokit-plugin-create-pull-request). They have a function octokit.createPullRequest() in their documentation. I am at a point where I need to know the datatype of the value it returns. Is it an array or an object? Or is it another datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns a pull request object, with the properties you see in the example response https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request.